# center and fit boundaries of geojson multiple polygon data

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am trying to center and fit the boundaries of multiple geojson polygon features on my `google.maps.Map`.

See this ***non geojson*** [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/te8pL5qw) recreating the effect i'm after.

Is there an easy Google Map API 3 function to do this for geojson data?

See my code below and [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/fe2vworc/)

```
var map;

window.initMap = function() {

    var mapProp = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.8948201,-0.7333298),
        zoom: 17,
        mapTypeId: 'satellite'
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapProp);

    map.data.loadGeoJson('https://api.myjson.com/bins/g0tzw');

    map.data.setStyle({
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35
    });

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());

}
```

I need expert pointers on cleanest and best way approach this.

See working demo of my code above in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/fe2vworc/).

http://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/fe2vworc/

*I've included my geojson inline so you can see the polygons on the map.*

Comment: What do you want the bounds for?  To center and zoom the map to show the polygons?  I don't think there is any "easy" way, you have to add all the coordinates of all the polygons to the bounds object.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to re-create my non-geojson version http://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/te8pL5qw/ so all polys are visible in what ever size window

Comment: loadGeoJson has a callback, see the docs

Comment: I'm check that out now thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a quick example of how you can get your features bounds. This will just get each feature bounds, extend a `LatLngBounds` object and then fit the map with these bounds.

```js
let map;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: {
      lat: 0,
      lng: 0
    }
  });

  const permits = {
    type: "FeatureCollection",
    id: "permits",
    features: [{
        type: "Feature",
        properties: {
          name: "Alpha Field"
        },
        geometry: {
          type: "Polygon",
          coordinates: [
            [
              [-0.72863, 51.895995],
              [-0.730022, 51.896766],
              [-0.730754, 51.896524],
              [-0.731234, 51.896401],
              [-0.731832, 51.896294],
              [-0.732345, 51.896219],
              [-0.732945, 51.896102],
              [-0.732691, 51.895774],
              [-0.732618, 51.895531],
              [-0.732543, 51.895359],
              [-0.73152, 51.894751],
              [-0.731037, 51.894488],
              [-0.730708, 51.894324],
              [-0.72863, 51.895995]
            ]
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        type: "Feature",
        properties: {
          name: "Beta Field"
        },
        geometry: {
          type: "Polygon",
          coordinates: [
            [
              [-0.728004, 51.895658],
              [-0.72863, 51.895995],
              [-0.730708, 51.894324],
              [-0.731217, 51.893784],
              [-0.730992, 51.893709],
              [-0.730793, 51.893567],
              [-0.730734, 51.893435],
              [-0.730761, 51.89333],
              [-0.729696, 51.893244],
              [-0.729391, 51.89314],
              [-0.729249, 51.893586],
              [-0.728991, 51.894152],
              [-0.728525, 51.894983],
              [-0.728004, 51.895658]
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  };

  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {

    // Load GeoJSON.
    map.data.addGeoJson(permits);

    // Create empty bounds object
    let bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    // Loop through features
    map.data.forEach(function(feature) {

      let geo = feature.getGeometry();

      geo.forEachLatLng(function(LatLng) {

        bounds.extend(LatLng);
      });
    });

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
}
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<script async src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initialize"></script>
```

Comment: Dude, this is lovely. So much more simple than anything I've found online. But having trouble when loading json via `map.data.loadGeoJson`. Here's my json http://myjson.com/g0tzw. Here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/47hngs9e/ using `loadGeoJson` but it centers the map in the indian ocean. If you zoom out, you can see polygons are in the UK. I was having this same problem earlier when using `map.data.loadGeoJson`.

Comment: Ah is the `loadGeoJson` loading too late for the forEach loop to get the data, do I need use a callback on `loadGeoJson`. Your code is so clean, how would you approach this?

Comment: I've done it like this http://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/47hngs9e/5/ would you say this is the best way to approach this?

Comment: Yes, in my example I used `addGeoJson` as you provided the sample data but this doesn't have a callback method. `loadGeoJson` has one though so yes, that's the way I would do it too.

Answer (score 1):

Props to [@MrUpsidown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1238965/mrupsidown) for providing the working method to `fitBounds`.

I'm posting this answer to show my final solution based on [@MrUpsidown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1238965/mrupsidown) answer using GeoJson data via `loadGeoJson()`

Here is my readable GeoJson here http://myjson.com/g0tzw

```
// initiate map
window.initMap = function() {

    // permits json
    var permits = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/g0tzw';

    // map properties
    var mapProp = {
        zoom: 17,
        mapTypeId: 'satellite'
    };

    // google map object
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapProp);

    // load GeoJSON.
    map.data.loadGeoJson(permits, null, function () {

        // create empty bounds object
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        // loop through features
        map.data.forEach(function(feature) {

            var geo = feature.getGeometry();

            geo.forEachLatLng(function(LatLng) {
                bounds.extend(LatLng);
            });

        });

        // fit data to bounds
        map.fitBounds(bounds);

    });

    // map data styles
    map.data.setStyle({
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35
    });

}
```

I'm calling `initMap` via...

```
 <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<?=$gmap_api?>&callback=initMap"></script>
```

See working demo here.

http://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/eg3vj17m/